# FollowEntity effecting the result of pickEllipsoid in 2d

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have a working solution to calculate the bounds of the viewport using the pickEllipsoid() function provided by the Cesium.Viewer.camera. It works for 2D and 3D. The picking part looks like this:

```
getLatLonFromPixel = function(viewer, x, y) {
       var pixel = new Cesium.Cartesian2(x, y);
       var ellipsoid = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid;
       var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(pixel, ellipsoid);
       if (cartesian) {
           var cartographic = ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(cartesian);
           return {
               latitude: Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude),
               longitude: Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude)
           };
       }
       return null;
};
```

I recently added in entity tracking using the Viewer.trackedEntity, while the tracked entity is set the bounds are correctly calculated in 3D, but not in 2D.

The tracked entity i am talking about is the trackedEntity property on the [Cesium Viewer](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Viewer.html) class.

I have included some calculated bounds from adding a console line.

```
3D with no entity being tracked:     3D with an entity being tracked:
north: 42.79154866747982,            north: 42.363594155001614,
east: -68.4164021205193,             east: -70.01866640806165,
south: 40.97543616484347,            south: 41.405727044270265,
west: -72.88803850857998             west: -71.78853254159573

2D with no entity being tracked:     2D with an entity being tracked:
north: 42.382604597019046,           north: 0.00024308806452135405,
east: -70.67532426625976,            east: 0.00044915764205976055,
south: 41.42473748628768,            south: -0.00024308806452135392,
west: -72.44519039979383             west: -0.0004491576420597605
```

The values I am getting for the 2d with an entity being tracked makes no sense. I have tried using the globe.pick(ray, scene), but that did not seem to work with the 2D map.

Any one have any idea what I might be missing? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in Cesium.  I filed [issue #3242](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/3242).

Comment: Interesting... That looks like the same thing! It very bazaar, I tried following the code path in Cesium when the trackedEntity gets set but was unable to determain the issue.
Then I thought it might be a projection issue, but it works fine when you are not following something.
My only other thought was that the ellipsis that is being used changes while following an entity, but it works in 3D. 

Hopefully the AGI guys will have some input!